# Capturing consecutive year ranges with break in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to write a query in hive to return a data with the year range if they are consecutive years along with the gap year, if there are gaps between the years.

I am trying to get my head around it, but can't seem to find the logic to achieve the results. How does hive logic work for this. Please help.

Input

```
group_no            year 
1111                2003
1111                2004
1111                2005
1111                2008
1111                2010
1111                2011
1111                2012
2222                2015
3333                2014
3333                2015
3333                2017
3333                2019
4444                2010
4444                2012
```

Output:

```
group_no year
1111    [2003-2005,2008,2010-2012]
2222    [2015]
3333    [2014-2015,2017,2019]
4444    [2010,2012]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem, where you want to group together rows having the same `group_no` and whose `year`s are consecutive.

Here is an approach using window functions: the idea is to use the difference between `row_number()` and `year` to build the groups. You can then aggregate once for each group of adjacent record, and finally aggregate by `group_no`.

```
select 
    group_no, 
    collect_list(
        case when min_year <> max_year 
            then concat(min_year, '-', max_year)
            else min_year
        end
    ) year
from (
    select group_no, min(year) min_year, max(year) max_year
    from (
        select  t.*, row_number() over(partition by group_no order by year) rn
        from mytable t
    ) t
    group by group_no, year - rn
) t
group by group_no
```

I am unsure whether hive supports `order by` in `collect_list()` as an aggregate function - it seems like it does when used as a window function though, so this might be better:

```
select distinct 
    group_no, 
    collect_list(
        case when min_year <> max_year 
            then concat(min_year, '-', max_year)
            else min_year
        end
    ) over(
        partition by group_no 
        order by min_year
        rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
    ) year
from (
    select group_no, min(year) min_year, max(year) max_year
    from (
        select  t.*, row_number() over(partition by group_no order by year) rn
        from mytable t
    ) t
    group by group_no, year - rn
) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GMB. Will try it out and keep you posted.

Comment: Hi GMB, Checked for the sql exceution, It works. However, noticed that there are some instances that it is not clubbing correctly If you observe, there shouldn't be 2007-2011 range, since it is already covered within the 1992-2020 range. For eg:|1030587|[1992-2020, 2007-2011]           |
|1030664|[1991-2020, 2007-2014]           |
|1030847|[1992-2007, 2007-2010]           |
|1031033|[1993-2014, 2007-2010]

Answer (score 0):

New range starts when `(year - prev_year) > 1 or (prev_year is NULL)`, you can take current year as first year for new range. 
Assign first_year to all rows then calculate last_year for each group `(group_no, first_year)`.

```
    with my_data as(
    select stack(14,
    1111, 2003,
    1111, 2004,
    1111, 2005,
    1111, 2008,
    1111, 2010,
    1111, 2011,
    1111, 2012,
    2222, 2015,
    3333, 2014,
    3333, 2015,
    3333, 2017,
    3333, 2019,
    4444, 2010,
    4444, 2012  
    ) as (group_no, year)
    )   

select group_no, array_sort(collect_list(case when first_year=last_year then first_year else concat(first_year,'-',last_year) end)) as year
from
(--calculate last_year
select s.group_no, s.first_year, max(year) last_year      
from
(
select group_no, year, 
       --New range starts when (year - prev_year) > 1 or (prev_year is NULL)
       --Calculate first_year for every row
       max(case when (year - prev_year) = 1 then NULL else year end) over(partition by group_no order by year rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) first_year
  from
(
select d.*,
       lag(year) over(partition by group_no order by year) prev_year
  from my_data d
)s  
)s
group by s.group_no, s.first_year
)s
group by group_no 
order by group_no
```

Result:

```
group_no  year
1111  ["2003-2005","2008","2010-2012"]
2222  ["2015"]
3333  ["2014-2015","2017","2019"]
4444  ["2010","2012"]
```